# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobServiceClient

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, asp.net-core-webapi

I am getting error InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobServiceClient while attempting to activate MyServices.Utilities.BlobService when running my WebAPI.

I am creating instance of my BlobService in the controller constructor.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I added
builder.Services.AddScoped(serviceProvider => new BlobServiceClient(blobStorageUrl));
in my Program.cs & it resolved the issue